# DropCreateDatabaseAlways - Drops database, or Schema?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm working on an assignment using EF6 and a university-provided Oracle database. Is there a way to perform DropCreateDatabaseAlways only on a specific schema?

I've not tried anything yet, because that's the root of my problem; this assignment would be easier if I could do DropCreateDatabaseAlways, but I'm nervous/unsure if it will drop schemas on the university DBMS other than my own.

All users have a schema on the Oracle database (11g) where the name is their student ID.

My concern is that if I use "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" it may affect other users on the shared DBMS.

Is there a way to specify I only want to affect my own schema? I'm pretty sure I only have permissions on my own schema anyway but of course I don't want to just blindly try things. The university in question has... temperamental tech setup.

Comment: What is "DropCreateDatabaseAlways"?  I've been working with Oracle rdbms for 20+ years and have never heard of that term.

Comment: It's an EF6 initialization class.
Right now, we're using "CreateDatabaseIfNotExist".

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx